# Entire Website Nested in One HTML Tag Disrupts Python Web Scraper

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, insert, tags

I am trying to create a Python WebScraper that takes data from the internet and converts it to a table that I will then export as a .csv file.  The sample website I am trying to get this program to work for is: https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/data/AJAX/O3_1/2018/06/06/AJAX-O3_ALPHA_20180606_R1_F229.ict

I was planning on using the `BeautifulSoup` library to do this, but I hit a wall once I realized that the entire text of the webpage of interest is nested in one tag, as shown in the images below. Does anyone know of any way that I can extract specific words and values from this single block of HTML text? For instance, I want to create 7 columns.  When I used the `findAll` function to find these column headers in the text, the entire block of text was returned when the results were printed since all of the text is nexted between the one `<p></p>` tag.

One hypothesis that I had was to add HTML tags between the lines of code and then access with Python, but I did not know if this was achievable.

After extracting the data with `BeautifulSoup` I plan on then passing this data to a `pandas` dataframe for easy export to .csv.
[image: Chrome DevTools of Entire Webpage]

[image: Entire HTML Transcript for the Page]

Comment: It's basically just plain text, no structure or formatting. You do it the same way as you would process an ordinary text file.

Comment: It's not intended for computer parsing, just for humans to read. So bone up on your natural language parsing skills.

Comment: So what I am gathering is that this is not a great first project for a novice programmer?

Comment: If you're still leaning, then yes this isnt a great first project. For your first, try something more structured. This is doable, but there is no real structure here, and will require a lot of babying.

Comment: regex may be useful here

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the best project for a beginner, I thought I would highlight the steps required to retrieve the table at the end of the page. This is not too difficult, and avoids the need for regex etc.

**Here are the steps:**

- **Create your account** at https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/
- **Login** to your account and navigate to your profile page: https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/profile
- Select the **Generate Token** tab
- Click on the **Generate Token** button
- Press the **Show token** button, and **copy the token** into the code below

[image: Generate a token]

**Paste your token into the code below:**

```py
# Navigate to : https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/profile
# Select the "Generate Token" menu item
# Click on the "Generate Token" button
# Copy and paste your token into the script below

# Instructions for downloading data from asdc.larc.nasa.gov : 
# https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewtopic.php?t=2330#confirm_external_link-modal

import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

# Identify the datafile and your token below
url='https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/data/AJAX/O3_1/2018/06/06/AJAX-O3_ALPHA_20180606_R1_F229.ict'
token='******paste-token-here******'
header={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

# Download the datafile
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
content = (response.content).decode("utf-8").split('\n')

# Identify the table header line in the content list
important_index = content.index('Int_Start, Int_End, TIME, G_Lat, G_Lon, G_Alt, O3')

# Keep the table data only
data = content[important_index:]

# convert the table data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(data)))

# Display the dataframe
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     Int_Start   Int_End     TIME   G_Lat   G_Lon   G_Alt      O3
0      69860.0   69868.0  69864.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  27.500
1      69870.0   69878.0  69874.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  28.545
2      69880.0   69888.0  69884.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  28.564
3      69890.0   69898.0  69894.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  29.818
4      69900.0   69908.0  69904.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  31.509
..         ...       ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
869    78550.0   78558.0  78553.6 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  39.584
870    78559.0   78567.0  78563.4 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  35.100
871    78570.0   78578.0  78573.6 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  34.150
872    78579.0   78587.0  78583.4 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  33.789
873    78590.0   78598.0  78593.6 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  32.193

[874 rows x 7 columns]
```